# ArangoDB AQL updating a document if and only if condition exists

Tags: arangodb, aql

I'm pretty new to ArangoDB so pardon if this question has an obvious answer. I've read the documentation and searched StackOverflow (from which the basic UPSERT/INSERT/UPDATE code is liberally pinched) and not found anything that seems be precisely relevant.

I am attempting to create and up a relatively simple database where records are of the form

```
{
    id: "some_id",
    keywords: [ "kw1", "kw2, . . . ],
    date: 12345678
}
```

I would like to create a new record or update the record if and only if the date (expressed as an integer number of seconds since epoch) is less than the new date.

My current AQL looks (somewhat schematically) like

```
UPSERT { id: "some_id" }
  INSERT { id: "some_id", keywords: [ kw1, kw2 ], date: new_date }
  UPDATE { date: OLD.date < new_date ? new_date : OLD.date, 
           keywords: OLD.date < new_date ? [ kw3, kw4, kw4 ] : OLD.keywords }
  IN kwds
```

This works but it seems to me that I'm doing more work than necessary, updating the record even if it has not changed.

I can't just assume that a new record will have a date greater than the old record since the input data are not necessarily in date order and there are far too many records to sort (the raw dataset is in excess of a terabyte in size).

I'm coding in python using the python-arango library if that is at all relevant.

Is there a better way to go about this?